# Adobe flash AS 2.0 true and false

Tags: flash, actionscript

I don't have really a question  i just want to learn how can i use in adobe flash whit ActionScript 2.0 in actions "true" and "false" and for what can i use it ? And please if you can give  me examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't do AS2. It is 10 years as obsolete and there are reasons to that. Do AS3 instead, it is faster, and structured (both language and Flash platform), and AS3 > AS2 in any possible way.

Then, your question. **Boolean** values are intended for data that have only two possible values in a certain context. Like AM or PM time, day or night, male or female, sold out or available, visible or hidden, right or wrong etc.

The use of **Boolean** variable is like saying "this data can have only 2 states" which cuts off other possibilities and simplifies the understanding of your program.

Ultimately, the condition and loop operators require **Boolean** values. In most cases **anything** you provide to these operators is auto-converted to **Boolean** so it's better to explicitly obtain the **Boolean** values out of your data to keep the logic straight.

Thus, **Boolean** variables are to store 2-state data and can be used in programming logic to control the flow of code.

```
// Conditional 'if..else' block.
if (ConditionA:Boolean)
{
    // Do this if ConditionA is true.
}
else if (ConditionB:Boolean)
{
    // Do this if ConditionB is true while ConditionA is false.
}
else
{
    // Do this if both ConditionA and ConditionB are false.
}

// The 'for' loop.
for (ExpressionA; ConditionA:Boolean; ExpressionB)
{
    // Do the loop while ConditionA is true.
    // Will not run if ConditionA is initially false.
}

// The 'while' loop.
while (ConditionA:Boolean)
{
    // Do the loop while ConditionA is true.
    // Will not run if ConditionA is initially false.
}

// The 'do..while' loop.
do
{
    // Do the loop while ConditionA is true.
    // Will run once even if ConditionA is initially false,
    // because the condition is checked at the end of the loop.
}
while (ConditionA:Boolean);
```

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Boolean.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: Thanks ! But  about AS2.0 have things better than AS3.0 like  the possibility  of put a Script in a button and a movieClip and tou need to see that the script is easy and in the adobe just shut them out because of the people who put on them virus .

Comment: @PauloR.Semedo I don't know where did you read about 'virus', but that's not true at all (just think of it, if that would be possible, they should've completely disabled AS1/AS2 both in Flash Player and Flash IDE rather than leaving it be for backward compatibility). Then, the profit of using **on** and **onClipEvent** constructions is feeble. It might seem simple and would do for very small projects, but for something medium to big - no, they won't as they negatively impact the project's integrity. Also, AS2 is slow and less capable. Not that I'm talking you into AS3, just stating the facts.

Comment: Thanks but i learn in my classes As2.0 and i dont know anything about AS 3.0